# How to back in running state from ADMIN state in Oracle WebLogic Server

Tags: weblogic, atg

in Oracle weblogic, in the server monitor I have a server in ADMIN state and I would go in the RUNNING state.

I tried to resume, suspend force, force shutdown, but nothing.

Comment: "but nothing" isn't particularly descriptive.  Are you getting an error?  What error?

Comment: On your `Deployment`, did you tell it to `Start > Servicing all requests` ?

Answer (score 2):

The server has entered admin state for a reason. You need to view the log files to try and find out what the reason is. It could be due to database connectivity failure, bad deployment etc etc. Once you analyze the reason behind the failure you need to resolve it and then startup WebLogic.

Answer (score 0):

The server has entered admin state and could never be started.
The installation process was stuck.

The root cause is the "clustered" option which was selected during the installation.

To solve this problem, i decided to uninstall the oracle Weblogic Server.

During installation, i removed the clustered mode in the "Configure Components" window.

Once the installation completed, the server stat entered in RUNNING mode.